# Which systems give the most blue options for events?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Sometimes at an event, because of your systems or crew, there'll be an extra blue option. These generally have better outcomes. For example:

> Giant alien spiders
>
> 1. Send the crew to help immediately! Giant alien spiders are no joke.
> 2. Leave them alone.
> 3. (Anti-Personnel Drone) Send your battle drone in to help.

I've noticed that the medbay often yields blue events, whereas the teleporter is rarely important. Precisely which systems / crew / weapons give the most blue options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a nice list of all the blue options, sorted by upgrade / crewmember, on the [FTL Wiki](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Blue_Options), but I'll summarise the results here.

Based on the count of possible blue options per upgrade, the following are the choices most likely to give you blue options:

- **Augmentations** - Long Ranged Scanners, by far
- **Crew** - Lanius, with Slug second
- **Drones** - Repair
- **Ship** - only one blue event, with the Rock Ship
- **Sub-systems** - Sensors
- **Systems** - Medbay (Hacking and Teleporter rank highly too)
- **Weapons** - Fire Bomb or Missile

This does not take into account the relative frequency of the events for which a blue option appears, nor the required level of system upgrade required for the blue option to work / be available, nor the relative ease in obtaining / starting with any of these options - but choosing from these upgrades (and generally aiming for at least level 2) will give you the best chances, if that's what you're going for.

Bear in mind that not all blue options are necessarily *best* or even *effective* options, either; for example, I recall an event where a ship asks you to donate missiles, and with a missile weapon equipped you can offer to fire one at them. Understandably, they're not keen on that idea.

Comment: Haha. I was wrong about the teleporter.

Comment: I think you forgot about the Engi on crews.

Comment: @ChinoCarlo Based on that article, Engi crew offers 8 blue options, Lanius 11 and Mantis 10. It's a close call but Lanius and Mantis are definitely the most beneficial in that sense.