# How to achieve the 'Diplomatic Immunity' achievement?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

> *"While using the Federation Cruiser, use your crew in 4 special blue event choices by sector 5."*

What's 'special blue event choices'?

Any tips / guidance regarding this achievement? like - best sectors to chose?

Comment: Related - this doesn't quite answer your question, but it does identify which systems and crew net the most blue options. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185130/which-systems-give-the-most-blue-options-for-events/185138#185138

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. "Special blue event choice" is an event option that has blue color. It means your system/crew member is being used to solve the event. This special option does *not* appear if you don't have the required system/crew.

   Example: [Unknown Disease on Mining Colony](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Unknown_Disease_on_Mining_Colony) - has the special blue option for either Rock or Engi crew member (Also medbay, but this achievement requires using crew, not systems)
2. As for *where*, it really depends on your crew. Often events in sector of particular race require crew member of the same race. There's also some luck involved - not every event have special blue option, and you don't see all events during a playthrough.

A full list of blue options *based on crew members* - which are required for that specific achievement - can be found on the FTL Wikia [here.](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Blue_Options#Crew)